# Duplicate emails being sent from Power Automate Flow. Using multiple Selectable column is issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, power-automate, flow, powerapps-canvas

Hoping to get some insights / direction here. I posted on the community MS forum but no-one really help. I'm not very technical and have been battling for months to build a full solution anyways.

Scenario: I have a SP List with columns. One of the columns I a multi-select column. I trigger a MS Flow when a certain column value changes. This all is working except the Power Automate flow when adding the multi-selectable field in the Send Mail(v2) action it adds as a (Apply to Each).

Now the flow initiates "duplicate" emails for each selected property of that column.

Can anyone help?

Thanking you in advance. I can export the flow to anyone who can help.

EDIT: Just adding my entire flow here...
[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

[image: PArt 3]

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a string variable to capture all emails and then finally use that in string variable in email action like below:

[image]

Ensure that within "Append to string variable" you add **semicolon** towards the end as a separator.

**References**:

1. [Send one e-mail to multiple selection person or group column](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-one-e-mail-to-multiple-selection-person-or-group-column/td-p/841370)
2. [Multiple selection people picker causes multi emails](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Multiple-selection-people-picker-causes-multi-emails/td-p/564839)
3. [Flow I need to send email to multiple user](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-I-need-to-send-email-to-multiple-user/td-p/476200)

Comment: Ah Ganesh ..im sorry i'm trying to understand your solution. Again i'm not very technical im just not sure where to add this?.....

Comment: What is "Vandalism Des..." in apply to each in last image? What is the column type (multiple selection choice?). Do you want to send one email per selection or single email with all selection values shown in email body?

Comment: Hi Ganesh - yes that's the "offending" column. It is the multi-select column in the Shoeproint list, ?users can select up to 9 possible selections . If they select more than one item. Than one mail PER item is sent... I need to restrict that. I will probably leave that field out of the email if i cant get this right..

Comment: You need to convert this multi-value (array) column to single string variable to use in email body. Follow [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Send-by-email-for-Sharepoint-multiple-choices-column/td-p/812251) and [this](https://tomriha.com/how-to-convert-array-to-a-string-in-power-automate/).

Comment: Yes ive gone through these posts. Will try again . Thanks

Comment: @LaurenceSher Please don't add "Thank you" as an answer. Please [accept this post as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.