# How to remove HTML in email output generated by Power Automate for multi-select columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, power-automate, flow, multi-select

My power automate solutions works fine for my single value columns, but I can't figure out how to identify and pull out the LookupValue(s) from the array of a multi-select columns.

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(SP.FieldUserValue)"},"results":[{"LookupId":2886,"LookupValue":"John Doe","Email":"john.doe@abc.com"}]}
```

I appreciate any help solving this.

[image]

Comment: Will there be only one user selected all the the time in multiple selection field?

Comment: No, in some cases there will be multiple names in the section field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below expression instead of using "Outputs" from compose action:

```
@{item()['LookupValue']}
```

If you are adding expression from Dynamic content > Expression popup, then use:

```
item()['LookupValue']
```

**Example**:

[image]

Don't forget to click on "OK" or "Update" after adding expression.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just had to modify it to item()['DisplayName']

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Ok after further testing what happens with the item()['DisplayName'] it displays the current name, not the previous name captured in the HTTP request.

Comment: Use "Outputs" of compose action as input to "Apply to each" action.

Comment: That works for cleaning up the previous name captured in the HTTP request, but now I can't get it to display the current name. (i.e.) It has changed from Joe to John. When I mess around with expressions and use triggerOutputs()?['body/CASC'] I get the whole CASC user info; name, email, id, etc.).

Comment: Use this: `triggerOutputs()?['body/CASC']['DisplayName']`. As you are using multiple selection field and if you want to concatenate multiple user names, you can create a variable, loop on multiple selection column and gather all values in single variable. Then use this variable in email action. Refer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303509/duplicate-emails-being-sent-from-power-automate-flow-using-multiple-selectable

Comment: The links worked to help solve the issue; thank you