# Power Automate - Send an email to multi-select people picker value(s)

Tags: power-automate, email, powerapp, people-picker, multiple-values

I have a Power Automate flow that triggers when a Form (PowerApps) is submitted to sharePoint.  One of the columns is a multi-select people picker (Other Approvers).  So if the requestor wants to add multiples approvers to look at their item, they can.  The requirement then is for when an item is submitted, One email gets sent to the identified manager and approver (there must be at least one).  This isn't an issue unless the user populates more than one Approver.  What's currently happening is when the user populates more than one, the flow sends one email per Approver, rather than sending one email to all.

In my Send an Email action, I have the field (Other Approvers Email) as a recipient in the "To" line.  If the user selects 2 Approvers, two emails will go out.

I want this to remain only ONE email be sent to the Initiator, and any Approvers that get populated.  Right now the flow splits it up into multiple emails.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299759/having-a-problem-with-apply-to-each-in-a-simple-email-flow/299761#299761) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303509/duplicate-emails-being-sent-from-power-automate-flow-using-multiple-selectable/303512#303512).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out actually.  Basically I added an Initialize Variable (String).  Then added an Append to String Variable + Apply to each.  I then used this variable in the emails.